# Ubuntu installation freeze from USB (Gigabyte P15)

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, live-usb, usb-installation, rufus

I just got a new laptop (a Gigabyte P15 with FreeDos pre-installed) but I want to install Ubuntu (16.04).

I prepared my USB key with Rufus and the Ubuntu 16.04 .iso. It went well.

Now, I boot on the USB from the new laptop and get stuck with the Ubuntu logo (and the little dots under it). Nothing else happens. For hours. (I tried several times). The dots don't change colors like they ususally do.

I tried to set boot mode in UEFI and Legacy OS: it didn't help. In UEFI mode, I also tried to run the option "Try Ubuntu" (without installing it). I got stuck on the same screen with the Ubuntu logo.

What can I try ?

Thanks

Comment: The second link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) worked ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Change the Boot mode from UEFI to Legacy in BIOS setting. Then check.
If there is only UEFI mode then it will work slow.

Comment: it was already in Legacy OS